# Javascript and html: window updates before document

Tags: javascript, html

As you can see in the code below, I want to run the loop 3 times and in each run write a line to the document. However, when I open the page, the alert message pops up 3 times and only then I see the new words on the page.

Why is it happening? Is there a way to update the document while still in the loop?
I'm guessing it's related to the "window" and "document", but I'm not quite sure how they work... Anyway, thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>

        var words = ["please", "print", "me!"]

        for (word of words) {
            alert("don't mind me!");
            document.write(word + "</br>")
        }

    </script>
</html>
```

[image: gif of the page]

Comment: No it is related to the screen redrawing.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is, that the browser will run the whole loop **before rendering** the `HTML`. 
This could get solved by "exporting" the inner of your loop into a `function` like i did below:

```js
var words = ["please", "print", "me!"]

for (word of words) {
  write(word);
}

function write(word) {
  alert("don't mind me!");
  document.write(word + "</br>")
}
```

While the solution above won't work with chrome, i've found out an other solution:

```js
var words = ["please", "print", "me!"]

write(words, 0);

function write(words, i) {
  if (i >= words.length) return;
  alert("don't mind me!")
  document.body.innerHTML += words[i] + "</br>";
  i++;
  setTimeout(() => {
    write(words, i)
  })
}
```

In this case the `function` is looping by its own and using a `setTimeout` without an given delay (so its using the default).

Since `document.write()` on a closed document stream will automatically call `document.open()`  (which will clear the document), you should use `document.body.innerHTML = ...` instead.

Feel free to ask, if anything is unclear.

Comment: @Nicolas could it be, that your the output gets hidden by your alertbox? On my screen i am able to see, that each word is added after closing its alert.

Comment: In my screen, it is not redered until the three alert are done showing. What browser are you using ?

Comment: or are you using chrome? found out that it will work on edge and firefox like a charm, but chrome is still running the whole javascript before rendering the HTML.

Comment: I'm using chrome, that might be the problem, let me test on other browser

Comment: It does work fine in FF. I can't test Edge ( linux )  but i assume it does too. This might be something you want to clarify in your answer. Otherwise, good job !

Comment: Found a working solution by trying several things to get it work on chrome. Updated my answer. Thanks a lot for the information, that there still was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

that's because Javascript is *FAST* ! No but really, you could use the function `setInterval` to be run every second, rather than using a loop. This will leave time for the dom to be updated. :

```js
var words = ["please", "print", "me!"]
let counter = 0;

let interval = setInterval(() => {
    // we access the value, in the array, at the 'counter' index, then increment it.
    let word = words[counter++];

    alert("don't mind me!");
    document.write(word + "</br>")

    if(counter >= words.length) {
      //all words were shown, we clear the interval.
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Its not because Javascript is fast, the problem is that the browser will run the whole loop before rendering the HTML. :)

Answer (score -1):

Because document.write() "writes directly into the page text, while the DOM is not yet built." The call to document.write only works while the page is loading.
If we call it afterwards, the existing document content is erased.
I'm citing documentation at https://javascript.info/modifying-document#a-word-about-document-write

Comment: "If we call it afterwards, the existing document content is erased." — It's not being called afterwards. Nothing is being erased.

Comment: @Quentin, Yes, clearly, not in this example. I was just citing the behaviour(